# How to find the function?

Tags: puzzle

I need to find a function that takes two integers as input and outputs an integer.

Input : $28$ $1$
Output : $68$

Input : $39$ $1$
Output : $90$

Input : $90$ $1$
Output : $81$

Input : $15$ $2$
Output : $40$

Input : $123$ $2$
Output : $17$

Input : $114514$ $1919$
Output : $16$

Comment: Does it have any patterns? Or it is random! :)

Comment: Pattern in Input?

Comment: Inputs are random.

Comment: Nope, I mean is there really a relation or pattern between input and output?

Comment: Where did you get this?

Comment: I found the pattern.Suppose first input is n and second m then the answer is sum of square of digits of n m number of times.

Comment: Good for you. You knew it before asking this question, I'm sure